# returning the table head value in google visualization tables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a JavaScript application using Google Visualization API.

```
 /* Define a table */
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'chart2',
          'options': {
            'sortColumn': '-1',
            'allowHtml' : 'true',
          },
          'style' : {
                'white-space' : 'nowrap'
          }
        });

 google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select',
                function (){
                    var tablewrapper = table.getChart();
                    var tabledata = table.getDataTable();
                    var value = $('.google-visualization-table-tr-head td').html();
                    console.log(value);
                    //var columnId = tablewrapper.getColumnDescriptions();
                    //console.log(tablewrapper);
                    /*var columnIndex = tablewrapper.getViewColumnIndex(); 
                    var selection = tablewrapper.getSelection();
                    for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                        var item = selection[i];
                        console.log('{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}');
                        var properties = tabledata.getRowProperties(parseInt(item.row));
                        console.log(properties);
                    }
                    */
                }
        );
```

Above is the definition of my listener. My goal is either to get the `columnIndex` or return the `table head name`, or the `entire column`. If I can get the `columnIndex` returned, then it's straight forward. However, if I have the `column header name`, I can map it to a hashtable, and retrieve the `columnIndex`. If I have the entire column, I want to return the first element of the array, which is the id.  However, I don't know how to accomplish neither of those tasks. Could someone please help me with that? Either using the Google's Visualization API or `JQuery`